Is the closed unit ball in a RKHS closed in $ L^2$ norm?
Background and notations
Let $\mathcal{X}$ denote an input domain. Let $H$ denote the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) induced by the Radial basis function (RBF) kernel with bandwith 1, which is defined as the positive-definite kernel
$$k(x,y) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|^2\right)$$
$H$ is space of functions from $\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$. The functions in $H$ satisfy the reproducing property, stated as follows
$$(\forall f\in H) (\forall x\in \mathcal{X}) f(x) = \langle f, \phi(x)\rangle_{H}$$
where the feature map $\phi(x) : \mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$(\forall x'\in \mathcal{X})\;\phi(x)(x') := k(x,x')$$
Namely, the positive definite kernel $k$ induces a feature map $\phi$.
Using the reproducing property, we can now show that $H$ continuously embeds into $L^2(\pi)$, where $\pi$ is any probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$. We denote this embedding by $\iota$, and it's used in the statement of the question.
Indeed, we have $$\|\iota(f)\|_{L^2}^2 := \int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x)^2d\pi(x) \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}}\langle f, \phi(x)\rangle_{H}^2\;d\pi(x) \leq \|f\|_{H}^2$$
due to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the reproducing property for the RKHS, that allows us to express $$f(x) = \langle f, \phi(x)\rangle_{H},\quad k(x,x') = \langle \phi(x),\phi(x')\rangle_{H}$$
for any element $f$ of the RKHS, and the fact that $\langle \phi(x),\phi(x)\rangle_{H} = k(x,x)\leq 1$ due to the boundedness of the positive-definite kernel $k$.
Question
Consider the closed ball defined as follows
$$B = \{\|f\|_{H}\leq 1\}$$
By definition $B$ is a closed ball with respect to the RKHS norm $\|\cdot \|_{H}$. Let $\iota$ denote the continuous embedding from $H$ to $L^2(\pi)$, which is shown to exist in the above section. Is the image $\iota(B)$ of $B$ under this embedding a closed set (w.r.t. the $L^2(\pi)$-topology)?

Could you format it better for easy reading and avoid acronyms ? Also explain where you struggle

Please clarify your acronyms or provide additional details. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're talking about.

Thanks for the helpful comments. I've rewritten the question to introduce the background first.

As a continuous linear map, $\iota$ is also weakly continuous and the unit ball of a Hilbert space is weakly compact. Hence, $i(B)$ is weakly compact and hence weakly and thus norm closed.

@Jochen Thanks!
